# LinkedIn Api Callback expires session

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, session, linkedin-api

I have TYPE in session e.g. `Session["TYPE"]`.
I access `LinkedIn Api` to get a LinkedIn user profile but after authentication in `LinkedIn Api` when `Redirect URL` is called back my session is expired, which means now `Session["TYPE"]` is null.

Same process is working perfectly on my development server, there is no session expire issue, but when I deploy it on live server this issue arises.

Why is the session state expired or cleared after the user is being redirected from LinkedIn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your getting redirected to the same domain name?

The session state uses cookies to persist a unique identifier in the web browser. After accepting the access in LinkedIn, you are redirected to your app. As you may know, cookies apply to only one domain. If the domain name is different, then the session cookie is not there and your session variable is not loaded.

Comment: Yes I am redirected to the same domain name.

Comment: Well SandRock you were up to the mark. Problem was "www" if my redirect URL is with www say "www.google.com" it works fine.
But if my redirct URL is without www say "google.com" it understand it as new domain hence no session cookie there.
So I marked your reply as answer. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the session-state module is disabled or badly configured on your production environment?

Verify [sessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is enabled and configured in your Web.config.

```xml
<system.web>
  <sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="20"
                cookieName="sessionState" mode="InProc" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: I added above line in my web.config but same result.
When redirected back from linkedin api to my application session is expired.